# Custom PictureBox with the title above

Tags: c#, controls, picturebox

I can't find a way to draw a custom control with image and text above it so I could  use it as a Drag Drop object. Both text and image path are fetched from XML file. I tried with custom class that would extend PictureBox, but couldn't do it. Images are quite small (65x55px average), but the title can be quite long sometimes so I usually ended with text that was drew only partially. Help anyone?

Comment: Are you talking about winforms? If so, I recommend you add a winforms tag.

Comment: In the case where the size of the title extends the size of the image as you describe above, what is the desired behavior of your custom PictureBox? Make it bigger so the title fits, then center the image below it? Make the title multiline, increasing the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a UserControl! It's like a reusable piece of form real estate. In the UserControl you place a PictureBox and a Label. You can do this right in the Visual Studio GUI. Then look up a drag drop tutorial and and add those events to the UserControl.

Comment: Ok I've created a UserControl with a label and picturebox beneath. Now when I add dynamically this control to my drag drop panel all event handlers stopped working and are not firing.

Comment: I hope that you mean that you created a UserControl with a Label and PictureBox *inside* it. That's what UserControls are - a reusable piece of form. If that's the case, set your drag drop events on the *UserControl*. Here's a tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dandtutorial.aspx. In these events you will asign text to your Label and an image to your PictureBox.

Comment: Problem is I try to attach event listeners on added UserControl and all events are not working (not firing)

Comment: Are you following the tutorial? Here's one that *verbatim* includes adding drag/drop events to a UserControl: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/UserControlDragDrop.aspx. But keep in mind this is probably *not* what you want. You *do* want to have your UserControl intercept the events. Remember to set AllowDrop to true.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider making a custom control for that. Make a custom control with a pictureBox and a label.